# usbDeviceefaultInterfaceBulkInPipes[0] cannot find device

Tags: c#, uwp, usb

I'm linking the stm32 to hololens via Windows.Devices.Usb . The program stop at the usbDevice.DefaultInterface.BulkInPipes[0], but if I run the Microsoft Sample, it can successfully execute. I'm really confused about where the mistake is!! Can anyone help?

````
    UInt32 vid = 0x07E4;
    UInt32 pid = 0x07E4;
    string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid);
    var device = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
    UsbDevice usbDevice = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(device[0].Id);
       
    UsbBulkInPipe bulkIn = usbDevice.DefaultInterface.BulkInPipes[0];
    DataReader reader = new DataReader(bulkIn.InputStream);  
    UInt32 bytesRead = 0;

   
    bytesRead = await reader.LoadAsync(bulkIn.EndpointDescriptor.MaxPacketSize);
    ```
<pre>
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess
</pre>
````

Comment: Have you add the custom `DeviceCapability` into [`Package.appxmanifest`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L69) file

Comment: Thanks A LOT!!!!! I successfully fix it!

Answer (score 0):

> usbDeviceefaultInterfaceBulkInPipes[0] cannot find device

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-connect-to-a-usb-device--uwp-app-), and add the specific custom `DeviceCapability` into Package.appxmanifest file

For example

```
<DeviceCapability Name="usb">

      <!--MUTT Device-->
      <Device Id="vidpid:045E 078E">
        <Function Type="classId:ff * *"/>
      </Device>
```